# Solspace User + Focuslab config member password reset link returns 404

Tags: solspace, members, focus-lab-master-config, forgot-password

- EE 2.9.2
- Solspace User 3.5.1

I've got a front-end member "forgot password" form on a site that uses Solspace User and Focuslab config and I'm removing index.php with .htaccess.

My profile_trigger config value is hardcoded in the Focuslab config to an obscure string:

```
$env_config['profile_trigger'] = '1ue985h60r92ynd9475ht9v7'; //rand(0,time());
```

This usually this works like a champ, but the password reset link in the email is going to EE's 404 page.

```
https://domain.com/1ue985h60r92ynd9475ht9v7/reset_password?&id=qU4lQ64d
```

I've tried inserting index.php into the URL string to no avail:

```
https://domain.com/index.php/1ue985h60r92ynd9475ht9v7/reset_password?&id=qU4lQ64d
```

.htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

#
# REMOVE WWW
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://aoma.edu/$1 [R=301,L]

#
# FORCE HTTPS
#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)% https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I can't find anything wrong with this setup but EE keeps showing 404 on the reset_password link.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your User code in the above question? Have you had a look at the `password_reset_template=""` parameter (http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/forgot_password/#password_reset_template)? From the docs: "_Without this parameter, User will send the default reset token to the user which will use ExpressionEngine's built-in reset password form._"